# How can I create circular cladograms in R?

Tags: r, plot, phylogeny, ape

I want to produce a circular cladogram in R. I was trying out the ape package and could produce something like this:

```
plot(tree,'f', use.edge.length=F)
```

[image]

Now I am not really happy with how the edges look like here. I tried out the [evolview](https://www.evolgenius.info/evolview/) webserver, which got me something like this, which looks much nicer, especially regarding the edges.
[image]

Can anyone suggest other R packages or a different approach with the ape package, to get similar results to the evolview tree?

Comment: https://guangchuangyu.github.io/ggtree-book/chapter-ggtree.html This ggtree package might be useful in your situation

Answer (score 0):

The two main differences that stand out to me are the size of the labels and the relative lengths of the edges.

Label size can be controlled using the `cex` graphical parameter (using `par()`, or as a parameter to `plot()`).

Uniform edge length can be added to the tree by replacing the `$edge.length` property with a vector of `1`s:

```r
par(cex = 0.8) # Shrink text
tree$edge.length <- rep_along(1, tree$edge.length)
plot(tree, 'f', use.edge.length = TRUE)
```